# How do i assign a single keyboard shortcut to run multiple languages in Visual Studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I am using Visual Studio code and I am programming in 2 languages. The default keyboard shortcut for mac is not quite comfortable for me. Hence, I changed it to `Cmd`+`R` but every time I switch to another language I have to change the keyboard shortcuts and not only assign shortcuts to the language I am using but also remove the older ones. So is there a way by which I can assign one kb shortcut to run all languages? it is also difficult to see which ones to add and which ones not to...

Comment: you can add a `when` clause to the keybinding and test for the `languageid`

Comment: @rioV8 please be a little more specific

Comment: read the keybind doc page of VSC